# Backbone model.get() is undefined inside model method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working on an app that requires that a subset of a collection be made by filtering for models that have a certain attribute value. I'm trying to do the filtering with a model method. Here's the collection code (Questions.js):

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/Question',
  'collections/Collection'
], function(_, Backbone, Question, Collection) {
  return Collection.extend({
    model: Question,
    url: '/questions'
  });
});
```

And here's the model reduced to just the filtering method (Question.js):

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/Model'
], function(_, Backbone, Model) {
  return Model.extend({

    categoryTextMatches: function(categoryText) {
    var t = this.get('category').text;
    console.info('t', t);
      return (t === categoryText);
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the app code that fetches the questions:

```
this.questions.fetch({
  data: this.set ? {set: this.set} : {},
  success: _.bind(this.renderQuestions, this),
  error: this.questions.parseError()
});
```

Here's the code in renderQuestions that tries to grab the filtered subset of questions:

```
var worryQuestions = new Questions().reset(this.questions.filter(this.getWorryQuestions));
```

And here's the getWorryQuestions function:

```
getWorryQuestions: function(model) {
  return model.categoryTextMatches('Worry');
}
```

What's happening is that every time the getCategoryTextMatches method runs, the console output shows the expected value ('t Sadness', 't Worry' etc.). However, there's also a JavaScript error coming from the model code in Question.js: "this.get(...) is undefined". Even though `this.get('category').text` shows the expected output in the console, it throws an error. I don't really understand how both can happen at once. Any help would prevent me from jumping off a bridge, thanks.

Comment: The above comment is on the right track, your only 'get' is within `categoryTextMatches` so would indicate an issue with your model here! Can you log out the model and post up? and I believe it should be `parseError` not `parseError()`

Comment: If I add: `console.info(model instanceof Backbone.Model);` inside getWorryQuestions, it outputs true. If I add: `console.info(model);` I see an object with the usual Model properties: cid, attributes, changed etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't run your code, but if you use method `Array#filter`, context is changed, so this in `categoryTextMatches` in not Model, but `this.question` category.

For protection use in `Model#constructor`:

```
return Model.extend({
    constructor: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'categoryTextMatches');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - gave that a try, but  no difference.

Comment: If I add: `console.info('this in categoryTextMatches', this);` inside categoryTextMatches, it outputs an object with the usual Model categories: cid, attributes, changed etc.

Answer (score 0):

It took a lot of diagnosing, but the problem stemmed from the fact that the models, representing three different types of questions, came with different collections of attributes - and some of them didn't have a 'category' attribute. I wish the error info was more explicit about that, it was just telling me that .get() was undefined, which was not in fact true.